# How can I use a regex on a mysql response to filter values using ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

How can I filter with ansible   slave_io_running/slave_sql_running and get the yes or no value please ?

```
stdout_lines:

    - '            Slave_IO_Running: Yes'
    - '            Slave_SQL_Running: No'
    - '              Replicate_Do_DB: '
    - '          Replicate_Ignore_DB: '
    - '           Replicate_Do_Table: '
    - '       Replicate_Ignore_Table: '
    - '      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: '
    - '  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: '
    - '                   Last_Errno: 0'
    - '                   Last_Error: '
    - '                 Skip_Counter: 0'
    - '          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 2595'
    - '              Relay_Log_Space: 1306'
    - '              Until_Condition: None'
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't work

```
when: yum_sec_upd.stdout_lines | select('search', 'Slave_IO_Running:') | list | length > 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to *extract* the value of `Slave_IO_Running`, you can do something like this:

```
    - set_fact:
        slave_io_running: >-
          {{ (yum_sec_upd.stdout_lines | select("search", "Slave_IO_Running:") | first).split(": ")[1] }}
```

This will set the variable `slave_io_running` to the extracted value.
Here's a complete test showing this in action:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    yum_sec_upd:
      stdout_lines:
        - '            Slave_IO_Running: Yes'
        - '            Slave_SQL_Running: No'
        - '              Replicate_Do_DB: '
        - '          Replicate_Ignore_DB: '
        - '           Replicate_Do_Table: '
        - '       Replicate_Ignore_Table: '
        - '      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: '
        - '  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: '
        - '                   Last_Errno: 0'
        - '                   Last_Error: '
        - '                 Skip_Counter: 0'
        - '          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 2595'
        - '              Relay_Log_Space: 1306'
        - '              Until_Condition: None'

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        slave_io_running: >-
          {{ (yum_sec_upd.stdout_lines | select("search", "Slave_IO_Running:") | first).split(": ")[1] }}

    - debug:
        msg: "running"
      when: slave_io_running

    - debug:
        msg: "not running"
      when: not slave_io_running
```

(Tested with ansible ansible 2.12.1)

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary

```yaml
stats: "{{ yum_sec_upd.stdout_lines|map('from_yaml')|combine }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  stats:
    Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 2595
    Last_Errno: 0
    Last_Error: null
    Relay_Log_Space: 1306
    Replicate_Do_DB: null
    Replicate_Do_Table: null
    Replicate_Ignore_DB: null
    Replicate_Ignore_Table: null
    Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: null
    Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: null
    Skip_Counter: 0
    Slave_IO_Running: true
    Slave_SQL_Running: false
    Until_Condition: None
```

The condition is trivial then

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: Slave IO is running
      when: stats.Slave_IO_Running
```

<sup>(Tested with Ansible 2.12.1)</sup>